Character Controller teleporting above ground
I have a capsule gameobject with character controller component and capsule collider, both with default settings, and a child camera object. When I move my character it randomly teleports to 0.33 on the y axis for some reason and I cant figure out why. It doesn't matter if I use my own code or the Example Code from the Unity website, it still teleports. Here are screenshots of my controller and collider to see settings:
(Note: I removed the capsule collider shown below, it was not necessary)

And here is my code:
public class Player_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Player Controller Components")]
[SerializeField] private CharacterController Controller;            //the character controller component to be refferenced
[SerializeField] private GameObject Main_Camera;                    //the camera object to be refferenced
[Space]

[Header("Player Controller")]
[SerializeField] private float MouseSensitivity = 2.0f;             //mouse sensitivity
[SerializeField] private Vector3 StartingRotation = Vector3.zero;   //a vector used to set the starting rotation
[SerializeField] private float MovementSpeed = 5.0f;                //standard movement speed
[SerializeField] private float BoostMovementSpeed = 15.0f;          //Boosted movement speed
[SerializeField] private Vector3 StartingPosition = Vector3.zero;   //a vector used for setting the starting position
[Header("Player Controller Clamping")]
[SerializeField] private float CameraMinAngle = -90.0f;             //the minimum of a range of rotation of the camera
[SerializeField] private float CameraMaxAngle = 90.0f;              //the maximum of a range of rotation of the camera
[Space]

[SerializeField] private float XBoundsMin = -25.0f;                 //the mminimum of a range of movement of the cursor
[SerializeField] private float XBoundsMax = 25.0f;                  //the maximum of a range of movement of the cursor
[Space]

[SerializeField] private float ZBoundsMin = -25.0f;                 //the maximum of a range of movement of the cursor
[SerializeField] private float ZBoundsMax = 25.0f;                  //the maximum of a range of movement of the cursor

[Space]
[Space]
[Header("Debuging")]
[SerializeField] private Vector2 MouseInput = Vector2.zero;         //vector used for mouse input rotation
[SerializeField] private Vector3 CharacterRotation = Vector3.zero;  //vector used for storing camera rotation
[SerializeField] private Vector3 MovementDirection;                 //a vector used for storing keyboard input and movement direction
[SerializeField] private float MovementSensitivity;                 //a float used for storing movement speed sensitivity of the player
[SerializeField] private Vector3 CurrentPosition;                   //a float used for storing the current position of the player

// Start is called once before the first execution of Update after the MonoBehaviour is created
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; //lock the cursor

    //find the compoennts require for the script to work
    Controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();       //find the character controller component on this gameobject
    Main_Camera = GameObject.Find("Player/Main Camera");    //find the main camera object that is the child of this gameobject

    //set the starting rotation
    StartingRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(StartingRotation.x,CameraMinAngle,CameraMaxAngle);     //clamp the starting rotation 
    CharacterRotation = StartingRotation;                                                   //set camera rotation to be equal to the starting rotation
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f,CharacterRotation.y, 0.0f);                  //set the player model starting rotation
    Main_Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(CharacterRotation.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);//set the camera starting rotation 

    //set the starting position
    transform.position = StartingPosition;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Rotation();

    MovementDirection.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");      //get the keyboard input for left and right
    MovementDirection.z = Input.GetAxis("Forward");         //get the keyboard input for forward and backward
    MovementDirection = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(MovementDirection, 1.0f);                    //clamp the movement direction vector to be no greater than 1
    MovementSensitivity = Input.GetButton("Boost") ? BoostMovementSpeed : MovementSpeed;    //if boost was pressed then use boost speed, otherwise use normal speed
    MovementDirection *= MovementSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;              //multiplye movement direction by movment speed to get a movement vector (direction + speed)
    MovementDirection = transform.TransformDirection(MovementDirection);    //convert local direction vector to global world space direction vector

    CurrentPosition = transform.position;                       //create a vector3 equal to the current position
    Vector3 NewPosition = CurrentPosition + MovementDirection;  //add the movement direction vector to the current position vector to get a new position
    NewPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(NewPosition.x, XBoundsMin, XBoundsMax); //clamp new position x between bounds
    NewPosition.z = Mathf.Clamp(NewPosition.z, ZBoundsMin, ZBoundsMax); //clamp new position z between bounds

    MovementDirection = NewPosition - CurrentPosition;  //subtract current position from new position to get new movement direction vector that is not out of bounds
    Controller.Move(MovementDirection); //move the player
}

private void Rotation()
{
    MouseInput.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * MouseSensitivity;         //get the mouse input horizontally for looking left and right
    MouseInput.y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * MouseSensitivity;         //get the mouse input vertically for looking up and down
    CharacterRotation.x += MouseInput.y;        //Rotation x (Up and down) equals mouse input y (Up and down)
    CharacterRotation.y += MouseInput.x;        //rotation y (Left and right) equals mouse input x (left and right)
    CharacterRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(CharacterRotation.x, CameraMinAngle, CameraMaxAngle);     //clamp the angle for looking up and down
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, CharacterRotation.y, 0.0f);                     //set rotation of the player
    Main_Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-CharacterRotation.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //set rotation of the camera
}
}

And here is the Unity example code from the link above which does the same thing. The only thing different is I changed controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>(); to controller = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>(); so that it wouldn't give me an error about not being able to add the character controller component
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
private CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 playerVelocity;
private bool groundedPlayer;
private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

private void Start()
{
    controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
    }

    // Makes the player jump
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && groundedPlayer)
    {
        playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2.0f * gravityValue);
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
}

I think it has something to do with the collisions between the character controller collider and the plane I have beneath the character which has a plane collider. 
With the plane moved down far enough below the player then the player does not teleport but when the plane is close enough beneath the player then it does teleport. See images below for more context. I don't know what could be causing this.

When the plane is close and I start the game then the character teleports:


But if I move the plane down far enough then the player stays put:



Can you select your character in the scene view so that we can see the wireframe gizmo of its collision capsule and check how that aligns with the visual capsule mesh? Having the transform in "Local / Pivot" mode also helps.
